# Can we consider Percona as an alternative to MySQL Enterprise?

Tags: mysql, percona

I am installing and testing the Percona Database to make some practices. and the question come alone
Its Percona an alternative to MySQL Enterprise?

Comment: certainly opinion based - you have not even listed features of interest

Comment: sure......you can consider it..........

Comment: The question is not about performance, is more about how it work, if i am learning with Percona database, i would have the same commands, configurations, etc. in bout database systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Percona team names their new Percona Server 5.6 ["Enterprise Grade MySQL with Outstanding Performance"](http://www.percona.com/resources/mysql-webinars/percona-server-56-enterprise-grade-mysql-outstanding-performance). Since they also provide [24x7 support](http://www.percona.com/products/mysql-support) one surely can take this into account as one possibility for enterprises.

If you have some detailed questions, you may ask them. Otherwise all answers may be kind of thin or vague here.